# How python choose the max letters from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, max, alphabet

Please tell me why python choose this:

```
print(max("NEW new"))

OUTPUT: w
```

Had i understood correctly: lowercase in python on the first place, on the second place uppercase?

Thanks!

Comment: Quote from python doc: `If one positional argument is provided, iterable must be a non-empty iterable (such as a non-empty string, tuple or list). The largest item in the iterable is returned. If two or more positional arguments are provided, the largest of the positional arguments is returned.`

Comment: Lookup the ASCII values of the characters!

Comment: The characters are evaluated according to ascii score and the max is taken...

Comment: Note that all the answers here which mention ASCII are plain wrong: `max` will get a iterator from the unicode string, which yields unicode code points. The comparison is done code-point by code-point using the code-value. This just happens to be the byte value for pure-ASCII strings. But the "ASCII-answers" are nonsensical for `max("ϓΞφ")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

max will compare the ASCII value of each character in the string. You can see for yourself what they are by trying out `ord('N')` or `ord(' ')` or `ord('w')`

here is the result from python  interpreter

```
>>> string = "NEW new"
>>> for s in string:
...     print(s , "--", ord(s))
... 
N -- 78
E -- 69
W -- 87
  -- 32
n -- 110
e -- 101
w -- 119
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just part of Python's definition for > on strings. It does lexicographic comparison with all lowercase letters coming after all uppercase letters. This is a result of the ordering of ASCII.

Since a string is an interable of characters, and max() goes through its iterable argument one by one and returns the one that compares > all the others, 'w' is the result.

Answer (score 0):

in the ascii code lower case letters have a higher code (I.E come later in the table) then upper case letters. you can see this by printing the ascii code for each letter

```
for letter in "NEW new":
    print(f'{letter} : {ord(letter)}')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
N : 78
E : 69
W : 87
  : 32
n : 110
e : 101
w : 119
```

as you can see lower case w has the highest (max) value.